# Use WHERE on result of SUM

Tags: mysql

So, I have this query working great

```
SELECT u.username,  SUM(kort) as total
FROM user as u 
LEFT JOIN userresult as r 
on u.userID = r.userID  
WHERE r.date >= '$date' 
group by u.userID
order by total DESC
```

But I want to remove those which the total is 0.

I tried this without any result

```
WHERE r.date >= '$date' AND total > 0
```

But am I not allowed to use WHERE on the result of SUM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change it to `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT u.username,SUM(kort) as total
FROM user as u 
INNER JOIN userresult as r 
on u.userID = r.userID  
WHERE r.date >= '$date' 
group by u.userID
order by total DESC;
```

or put the WHERE clause in the HAVING aggregation

```
SELECT u.username,SUM(kort) as total
FROM user as u 
LEFT JOIN userresult as r 
on u.userID = r.userID  
WHERE r.date >= '$date' 
group by u.userID
HAVING SUM(kort) > 0;
```

or put the whole thing in a subquery and test the total outside the subquery

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT u.username,SUM(kort) as total
    FROM user as u 
    LEFT JOIN userresult as r 
    on u.userID = r.userID  
    WHERE r.date >= '$date' 
    group by u.userID
    order by total DESC
) A WHERE total > 0;
```

The simplest and most sensible is the `INNER JOIN`

Comment: The inner join itself won't help if userresult.kort might have a value of 0.

Comment: But does the `INNER JOIN` eliminate the `total=0` row(s)?  The third solution involves a subquery.  I vote only for the `HAVING` solution.